# Question for covariance stationary process

Tags: stochastic-processes, covariance, stationary-processes

Given a random variable Y with characteristic function
 C(w) = E[exp(iwy)]  . Let the random process X(t) be defined as X(t)=cos(wt+y). Show that the process X(t) is covariance stationary if C(1)-C(2)=0.
I have tried expanding the characteristic function in the trigonometric form and using the result to prove stationarity but I'm still unable to solve it. Any hint will be helpful.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**

$$E[X(t)]{=E[\cos(wt+y)]\\=E\left[{e^{iwt+iy}+e^{-iwt-iy}\over 2}\right]\\=\text{const}}$$and$$E[X(t_1)X(t_2)]{=E[\cos(wt_2+y)\cos(wt_1+y)]\\={1\over 2}E[\cos(w(t_2-t_1))]\\+{1\over2}E[\cos (wt_1+wt_2+2y)]}$$since $E[X(t_1)X(t_2)]$ must be a function of $t_1-t_2$ so $E[\cos (wt_1+wt_2+2y)]=0$. The rest is easy.